# How to get more detailed exception in ABP?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, exception, aspnetboilerplate, exception-logging

I created a CrudAppService. When I invoke its dynamic API by using *swagger*, I get a generic `500` error with this description:

```json
{
  "result": null,
  "targetUrl": null,
  "success": false,
  "error": {
    "code": 0,
    "message": "An internal error occurred during your request!",
    "details": null,
    "validationErrors": null
  },
  "unAuthorizedRequest": false,
  "__abp": true
}
```

How can I get a more detailed exception to debug? Is there something I have to enable?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50912659/how-to-add-value-to-the-default-exception-response-in-abp/50916983

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check error in **Logs.txt**.

From the documentation on [Logging](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Logging#configuration):

> #### Configuration
>
> All configuration is done for Log4Net when you create your application from ASP.NET Boilerplate templates.
>
> ...
>
> It's defined in the **log4net.config** file of the application as shown below:
>
> ```xml
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
> <log4net>
>   <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
>     <file value="Logs/Logs.txt" />
> ```

Answer (score 21):

You can simply send the exception details to the client by enabling one of ABP's configurations (`SendAllExceptionsToClients`) in ***.Web.Core Module, like this:

```
public override void PreInitialize()
{   
    Configuration.Modules.AbpWebCommon().SendAllExceptionsToClients = true;
}
```

Then you get the exception details on the client. **Recommended only during development.**

Comment: I also have the mentioned problem. And the question was not about a _web project_ - it was about a lower level - _Application layer_ (CrudAppService), so we need to make some changes THERE.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `CurrentUnitOfWork`, you can catch the exception also and using 
`UserFriendlyException` you can throw the desired exception. `UserFriendlyException` is a specific type of exception so ABP directly shows exception message to the end user.

Example:

```
try
{
    await _repository.InsertAsync(...);
    await CurrentUnitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    throw new UserFriendlyException("user friendly exception message");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look into your project logs at `project.Host\App_Data\Logs.txt`.