# How can I debug ASP.NET Boilerplate Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, aspnetboilerplate

I am using the ASP.NET Boilerplate framework. I have added my code to web API. I am getting an error "An internal error occurred during your request!", So, I want to debug the API. Can anyone tell me how can I do that? when I call the web API, breakpoint should come in the Service project.

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete, verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get more detailed exception in ABP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48050689/how-to-get-more-detailed-exception-in-abp)

Answer (score 4):

Please follow the points below for the solution to your problem.

1. You can open the browser console and in the network tab you can see
   that which API is getting failed and you can also see the HTTP
   response code.
2. For debugging you can use the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48415479/6527049).
3. You can also see the full exception details in **Logs.txt** file on
   the **Web.Host\App_Data\Logs** path. For logging, you can refer this
   [document](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Logging#configuration).