# How to add value to the default exception response in ABP?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I want to add an ID (GUID) to the exception and:

1. Log it
2. Return it to the client json response

Where should I generate this log ID value and add it to the exception message that is logged. And where to change the following default response?

```
{
  "targetUrl": null,
  "result": null,
  "success": false,
  "error": {
    "message": "An internal error occurred during your request!",
    "details": "..."
  },
  "unAuthorizedRequest": false
}
```

I am using .NET Core version.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to disable displaying the message for a particular AJAX call, add `abpHandleError: false` into the abp.ajax options.

Or you can disable the default behavior of the framework exception wrapper

```
public class PeopleController : AbpController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [WrapResult(WrapOnSuccess = false, WrapOnError = false)]
    public JsonResult SavePerson(SavePersonModel person)
    {
        //TODO: save new person to database and return new person's id
        return Json(new {PersonId = 42});
    }
}
```

https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Javascript-API/AJAX?searchKey=wrap#asp-net-mvc-controllers

---

Another thing is; you can send exception details to the client by the below configuration

```
...
using Abp.Web.Configuration;
...
public override void PreInitialize() 
{
    Configuration.Modules.AbpWebCommon().SendAllExceptionsToClients = true;
}
...
```

https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Startup-Configuration#configuring-modules

---

Result Wrapping & Exception Handling:

ASP.NET Boilerplate does not wrap Web API actions by default if an action has successfully executed. It, however, handles and wraps exceptions. You can add the WrapResult/DontWrapResult attributes to actions and controllers for finer control. You can change this default behavior from the startup configuration (using Configuration.Modules.AbpWebApi()...). See the AJAX document for more info about result wrapping.

https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Web-API-Controllers?searchKey=wrap#result-wrapping-exception-handling

---

Wrapping Results

ASP.NET Boilerplate wraps the return values of dynamic Web API actions using an AjaxResponse object. See the ajax documentation for more information on wrapping. You can enable/disable wrapping per method or per application service. See this example application service:

```
public interface ITestAppService : IApplicationService
{
    [DontWrapResult]
    DoItOutput DoIt(DoItInput input);
}
```

https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Dynamic-Web-API?searchKey=wrap#wrapping-results

---

Lastly you can write your own ResultWrapperHandler...

```cs
public class CustomResultWrapperHandler : ResultWrapperHandler, ITransientDependency
{

    //...
    protected override void WrapResultIfNeeded(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpResponseMessage response)
    {

        //...

        base.WrapResultIfNeeded(request, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alper for the detailed answer. I simply want to add another attribute, which is Exception code (generated UID) and return it to the user. Then log it in the log serice to find it easy. Is that possible without writing my own wrapper ?

Comment: sorry no! write your own implementation.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get special message in some case you can use

```
throw new UserFriendlyException("your message");
```

the above code just effects on error message and doesn't show the details.
so its good option for production version.